# rvm install 1.9.X on lion hangs after extracting ruby source

Tags: rvm

Cleaning up, did rvm implode, installed fresh rvm with `--ruby` so I have 2.0.0 installed.

When trying `rvm install ruby-1.9.3 --autolibs=4`, the installation hangs right after the message that the src is being extracted. This happens with 1.9.3, ruby-1.9.3-p392, and 1.9.2 as well. I get a couple of dots, and then nothing further happens. Any suggestions?

Results with --debug on a 1.9.2 attempt.

```
$ rvm --debug install ruby-1.9.2 --autolibs=4
ruby-1.9.2 - install
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Remote file does not exist https://rvm.io/binaries/osx/10.7/x86_64/ruby-1.9.2-p320.tar.bz2
Remote file does not exist http://jruby.org.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/ruby-1.9.2-p320.tar.bz2
Remote file does not exist http://binaries.rubini.us/osx/10.7/x86_64/ruby-1.9.2-p320.tar.bz2
rvm_remote_server_url3 not found
No remote file name found
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.7/x86_64/ruby-1.9.2-p320.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_setup ruby-1.9.2-p320
rvm_autolibs_flag=4
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_requirements ruby-1.9.2-p320
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
requirements code for osx loaded
requirements code for osx_brew loaded
brew seems to be writable
Already up-to-date.
Found required packages: autoconf, automake, libtool, pkg-config, libyaml, readline, libxml2, libxslt, libksba, openssl, sqlite.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.
rvm_configure_flags+=( --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml )
__rvm_update_configure_env(1):CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/readline/include:
__rvm_update_configure_env(1):LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib:
__rvm_update_configure_env(1):CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include:
__rvm_update_configure_env(1):LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib:
__rvm_update_configure_env(1):CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/libxslt/include:
__rvm_update_configure_env(1):LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/libxslt/lib:
__rvm_update_configure_env(1):CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include:
__rvm_update_configure_env(1):LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib:
__rvm_update_configure_env(1):CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include:
__rvm_update_configure_env(1):LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib:
__rvm_update_configure_env(1):CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include:
__rvm_update_configure_env(1):LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib:
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_osx_compiler ruby-1.9.2-p320
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_architectures ruby-1.9.2-p320
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_gcc47plus ruby-1.9.2-p320
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_bison ruby-1.9.2-p320
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_smartos ruby-1.9.2-p320
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_sunos ruby-1.9.2-p320
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_openbsd ruby-1.9.2-p320
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_auto_conf_make ruby-1.9.2-p320
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_flags_docs ruby-1.9.2-p320
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_flags_tcltk ruby-1.9.2-p320
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_flags_shared_static ruby-1.9.2-p320
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_flags_threads ruby-1.9.2-p320
found compiler: gcc-4.2
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/jfnixon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #downloading ruby-1.9.2-p320, this may take a while depending on your connection...
No archive, downloading
Running(11): curl --fail --location --max-redirs 10 --create-dirs -C - -o ruby-1.9.2-p320.tar.bz2 http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.2-p320.tar.bz2
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 8770k  100 8770k    0     0   177k      0  0:00:49  0:00:49 --:--:--  123k
Downloaded archive checksum matched.
Log file: /Users/jfnixon/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p320/1366859728_extract.log
ls: /Users/jfnixon/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p320/1366859728_extract.log: No such file or directory
remove[ny]? y
[2013-04-24 23:15:34] __rvm_package_extract
__rvm_package_extract () 
{ 
    rvm_debug __rvm_package_extract:$#: "$@";
    typeset __tempdir __path __file __return;
    __return=0;
    __tempdir="$( TMPDIR="${rvm_tmp_path}" mktemp -d -t rvm-tmp.XXXXXXXXX )";
    __rvm_package_extract_run "$1" "$__tempdir" || __return=$?;
    if (( __return == 0 )); then
        for __path in "$__tempdir"/*;
        do
            __file="${__path##*/}";
            if [[ -n "${__file}" && -e "$2/${__file}" ]]; then
                \rm -rf "$2/${__file}" || __return=$?;
            fi;
            \mv -f "${__path}" "$2/" || __return=$?;
        done;
    fi;
    if [[ -n "$__tempdir" ]]; then
        \rm -rf "$__tempdir";
    fi;
    return $__return
}
current path: /Users/jfnixon/.rvm/src
command(3): __rvm_package_extract /Users/jfnixon/.rvm/archives/ruby-1.9.2-p320.tar.bz2 /Users/jfnixon/.rvm/tmp/rvm_src_71265
ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #extracting ruby-1.9.2-p320 to /Users/jfnixon/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320..^C
__rvm_rm_rf already gone: /Users/jfnixon/.rvm/tmp/71265*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like a endless loop, bugs should be reported to RVM directly => http://bit.ly/rvm-issues

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. I waited more than an hour for an operation that should have been completed in under 4 minutes. As it tuned out, for some reason a different version for ruby was installed on my Mac, outside of rvm. A simple `rm /usr/bin/ruby` did the trick.